# Javascript to change color of specific <li> of an <ul>

Tags: javascript, colors, html-lists

I'm trying to use javascript to change the color of a specific li of a ul, but my code is highlighting all subsequent li of the list. Here is the code:

```html
<ul list style type = "none">
  <li id = "l0">this is line one</li>
  <li id = "l1">this is line two</li>
  <li id = "l2">this is line three</li>
</ul>
```

```js
function highlight(name,color) {
  var a = document.getElementById(name);
  a.style.color = color;
}
```

When I call this with something like

```
highlight("l0","orangered");
```

it changes the colors of "l0" through "l2", instead of just "l0". I would very much prefer a solution using only javascript, rather than a 3rd party library. Thanks!

Comment: You code works, your error is somewhere else. http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/khAHh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a fiddle using your js function:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ahb8F/

It works fine, did you expect/want something else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Odd that the version I  made up on the fly for the post works, and my page doesn't. When I find the discrepancy I will post where I went wrong.

Comment: Stupid, stupid, stupid. My problem in the original code was a missing /li tag, so when that line was highlighted (which just happened to be the first line I was testing) it highlighted every subsequent line. In other words, memo to me: before posting look closer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7bMa/

Answer (score 0):

That's a bizarre bug. I've just tried doing what you did, and it worked fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4aGag/